# Angular: custom filter for recursive search in nested object

Tags: angularjs

I have some problem with filtering nested object. In select I choose the filter parameter(object value) and in input I type some text that searches it in object key. 
Tried to write custom filter with recursion for deep search but it doesn't work.
`input` is parameter for object in ng-repeat, `param1` is for select's ng-model and `param2` is for input's ng-model.

**JS**

```
  .filter('personFilter', function($filter) {
    return function(input, param1, param2) {
      var output = {};
      for (var prop in input) {
          if (typeof input[prop] == 'object' || prop != param1 && input[prop] != param2) {
              $filter('personFilter')(input[prop]);
          } else {
              output[key] = input[key];
          }
      }
      return output;
    }
```

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/83lPNRWFy6wa9U2FkMfH?p=preview 
I hope someone give me some advice

Comment: seems like data format is not valid. you should get an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` because format can be somehting like `[{'node1': {node2: ''}}]` not `['node1': {...}]`

Answer (score 0):

sorry, just dirty solution, have no time to refactor. Mb it save time to you

```
.filter('personFilter', function($filter) {
    return function(input, recursive, search) {
          return input.filter(filterFn);
          function filterFn(obj){
            var val, res;
            for (var prop in obj) {
                val = obj[prop];
                if (typeof val == 'object' && recursive) {
                    recursive = false;
                    res = res || val.filter(filterFn).length;
                    recursive = true;
                } else if(!recursive){
                    res = res || val == search;
                }
            }
            console.log(res, obj, recursive, search);
            return res;
          }

        }
```

with following markup

```
<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectParameter" ng-options="item.value as item.key for item in parameter track by item.value">      
    </select>
    <input ng-model="query" />

    <div ng-repeat="person in object.node1.node2.persons | personFilter:selectParameter:query track by $index">
     <!--   -->
        <p>Person: {{person.name}}, Children: <span ng-repeat="child in person.children track by $index">{{child.name}}, </span></p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and controller init like:

```
$scope.parameter = [
      {value: false, key: 'Person Name'},
      {value: true, key: 'Child Name'}
];
$scope.selectParameter = true;
```

Comment: Hi, it works strange :) http://plnkr.co/edit/wGeYk7OuFGCMc56usjk1?p=preview

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: See the plunker

Comment: I saw it. What do you mean under the strange?

Comment: I doesn't filter correct even in console. If I try to find by First name and type 'Peter' it also shows me 'Martin'. And if I have more than two select options? There are true and false in option values.

Comment: I'll be pleased if you help me to do this filter without recursive and pathsearch. I have this variation of filter http://plnkr.co/edit/83lPNRWFy6wa9U2FkMfH?p=preview but when I use it in my project, the divs in ng-repeat are not displayed. Perhaps, project doesn't like what is in ng-repeat: ng-repeat="consignment in result=(searchresult | consignmentFilter: selectParameter:query:this)"

Comment: Please write example input and expected output, 2-3 examples for your data. like filter(data, searchOnlyChildren, 'Peter') -> {name: 'Sonya', children: [{name: 'Peter'} ...]

Comment: Here's plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/dC3SFKzx3CyR7RE5UcLP?p=preview . Input is whole object, output is filtered object by select and input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124538/discussion-between-valery-kozlov-and-kipris).